# How to add trailing space after some number of character using select statement?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In each column, after first 5 characters I need to add/replace next 5 characters with '*' then add 10 more white spaces.

```
SELECT nameFirst, nameLast, number, fax 
FROM table_01
```

Expected result:-

```
Revol*****          Jenni*****          598-1*****          12345*****      
Jenit*****          Austi*****          598-1*****          12345*****          
Revol*****          Jenni*****          598-1*****          12345*****
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using bcp utility to export a text file. Need to format the file and hide actual information.

Comment: What would you like output if a column's value is less than five characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(nameFirst,5) + '*****          ',
   LEFT(nameLast,5) + '*****          ',
   LEFT(number,5) + '*****          ',
   LEFT(fax ,5) + '*****          '
FROM table_01
```

If you think you might want to use a variable later for the number of * and space characters, this technique might be better (and more readable) but uses keywords that are specific to tSQL:

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(nameFirst,5) + REPLICATE('*',5) + SPACE(10),
   LEFT(nameLast,5) + REPLICATE('*',5) + SPACE(10),
   LEFT(number,5) + REPLICATE('*',5) + SPACE(10),
   LEFT(fax ,5) + REPLICATE('*',5) + SPACE(10)
FROM table_01
```

**Update per your comment**
Assuming you want extra *'s for names with <5 characters. Here is an approach that should work.

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(nameFirst + replicate('*',5),5) + replicate('*',5) + SPACE(10)
   ...
FROM table_01
```

It is a little sneaky, but it avoids a longer inline conditional.

Comment: John. If nameFirst lenght is less than 5 char, is there any way I can add more *. Eg. nameFirst is 'Mia' then add 7 'asteriks' not five like 'Mia*******          '

Comment: Sure, just change `LEFT(nameFirst, 5)` to `LEFT(nameFirst + '*****', 5)`